# Edit a sharepoint 2013 site in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to know how to edit a sharepoint 2013 site in sharepoint designer 2013, as I cant find an icon that does this.In sharepoint 2010, there was an icon to edit in sharepoint designer 2010; but in 2013 there is not?

Answer (score 11):

If you click the "Page" tab you will get this option under the extended "Edit" button. It should read "Edit in SharePoint Designer".

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I havent found the edit in designer button either.  I just downloaded and installed Designer 2013 and pasted in the URL of the site I wanted to open and edit.  Worked the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways:

- Make click in "Page Tab" then under "Edit Button" press Edit in
  SharePoint Designer
- Open the website with SharePoint Designer "Open
  Site" and write your site URL.

Answer (score 0):

"Page" Tab
Click the Arrow under "Edit" 
and then "Edit in SharePoint Designer".

In my System this did only work when I wasn't in Editing Mode of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Open SharePoint Designer. Click on: `Open SharePoint Site`, and then simply paste the URL of your site that you want to edit.

This will connect to that site and let you navigate all the necessary files and folders of that site, and edit those in accordance.

Answer (score -2):

Under Library, Customize library, edit library, launch application